# XG-Transactions Fail in Google App Engine's Local Java Server -- Run fine when deployed on Live GAE

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, entity-relationship, entity-group-transactions

I'm need to use XG (Cross group) transactions across some of my entity groups in Google App Engine.  Unfortunately when I run any of these operations on my local Jetty (Eclipse) server, the App Engine development wrapper throws a "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: transactions on multiple entity groups only allowed in High Replication applications".

This is extremely frustrating, as the exact same XG transactions run absolutely fine once my application is deployed on the live GAE servers.  Does this mean I'll have to deploy my application any time I want to test my application now that I have XG transactions incorporated?  Any help is greatly appreciated.

P.S.  I'm using the low-level data store API because the original JDO layer I employed did not give me the loading detail granularity I needed, in case that makes a difference.

Comment: Sounds like a bug in the (beta!) SDK - have you reported it to google?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is a bug in the 1.5.5 SDK. Description and workaround are here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-appengine-java/iKLgAzFIU_s

Comment: Thanks for that solution, replacing GAE 1.5.5's "datanucleus-appengine-1.0.9.final.jar" with the unreleased "datanucleus-appengine-1.0.10.final.jar" from that link solved my problem!